# How to get the web app (itself) to tweet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I have a Rails 3 app that I would like to tweet certain status reports and so on.  I am using the [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter).  I have all the API keys and so on, and can actually tweet to a logged-in users account.  But this isn't what I want to do.

I want the app to tweet to its own account, "in the background" so to speak.  So, when the user does something, the app should tweet to its own account (not the user's) "this has been done."

Is there any way to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: How did you add this gem to your gemfile for rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working.  The trick was to make sure the account you are posting to is also the account where you register the app (it won't work if you just have the keys).  Then, just take the four keys (see below) and use the following code:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY'
  config.consumer_secret = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET'
  config.oauth_token = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET'
end

client = Twitter::Client.new
client.update('Hello, from Twitter Gem!')
```

Answer (score 0):

What's exactly your difficulty? Have you tried it already?

I never used the Twitter Gem, but with a quick look at its README it looked simple enough. You'll just have to create an account for your application and create an instance of `Twitter::Client` for that account.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it several ways.  The problem, so far, seems to be that when you create the instance and go to send a tweet (with .update), you get to an authentication screen.  But I don't want this: the app itself have to do the tweet to its own account (not the user's account).